# Ipfs website renders differently on different gateways

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ipfs

So I have deployed a starter template on ipfs.

On this gateway the sites styles are not applied.

https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmVeBe6GaarDRKKxLNJS672AHg98DYYouAxuby9P6qW1qg/

On this gateway the sites styles are applied.

https://bafybeidmp6t6chsfl74rf3o6xcjaosop2fo733klve6ji633t6ylbapcf4.ipfs.infura-ipfs.io/

What is the difference between these gateways, and how can one get consistent rendering on all gateways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your assets, stylesheets, and/or scripts are referenced by absolute paths which

- breaks on [path gateways](https://docs.ipfs.io/how-to/address-ipfs-on-web/#path-gateway) (e.g., `https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/<cid>/path/to/resource`)
- but works on [subdomain gateways](https://docs.ipfs.io/how-to/address-ipfs-on-web/#subdomain-gateway) (e.g., `https://<cidv1b32>.ipfs.gateway.ipfs.io/path/to/resource`)

Your site works fine on other subdomain gateways<sup>†</sup> too:

- https://bafybeidmp6t6chsfl74rf3o6xcjaosop2fo733klve6ji633t6ylbapcf4.ipfs.cf-ipfs.com/
- https://bafybeidmp6t6chsfl74rf3o6xcjaosop2fo733klve6ji633t6ylbapcf4.ipfs.dweb.link/

**†** See [IPFS Public Gateway Checker](https://ipfs.github.io/public-gateway-checker/) for a list of them.